# Export to html table csv not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, csv, export-to-csv

I have a html table with 16000 rows 5 columns. I am using the below script to export the table to csv but when the No. of rows are huge the screen goes blank and the export doesn't happen.

```
var ifrm =  document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.id = "txtExport";
ifrm.style.display = 'none';
document.appendChild(ifrm);  
txtExport.document.open("txt/html","replace");
txtExport.document.write('sep=,\r\n' +csvData);
txtExport.document.close();
txtExport.focus(); 
txtExport.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Export.csv")
ifrm.parentNode.removeChild(ifrm);
```

Can someone help me with this or suggest a workaround.

Comment: Do you just want to target the IE audience, because if I am not wrong the code you wrote might not work with other browsers.

Comment: If it will work on other browsers its good, but has to work on IE.

Comment: Please go through the code.

Comment: Take a look at [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Answer (score 0):

Your code might only work for, IE and not for other browsers, please correct me if I am wrong, but for the functionality you are asking, you can actually use [datatables](https://datatables.net/) for that.

The code is pretty simple:

```
<script>
  $(document) .ready(function(){
      $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          'csv', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
      });
  });      
<script>
```

*FYI:* I have created the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/qqjoLzvw/5/) as well,although it needs more references to other files, please look in to that once, on the left hand side.

Comment: I am looking for a solution using Javascript.